# FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options). Angular 15

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error on my firebase app, here is my service worker file firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from "@angular/fire/auth";
import {getMessaging} from "firebase/messaging";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
   messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX-XXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX",
  measurementId: "XXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXX"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = app.firestore();
const messaging = getMessaging();
```

Here is my messagingService file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";
import {AngularFireMessaging} from "@angular/fire/compat/messaging";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MessagingService {

  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
  }

  requestPermission() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      }
    })
  }

    requestForToken = () => {
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("./firebase-messaging-sw.js").then(function(registration) {
          console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration.scope);
        })
      }
    return getToken(getMessaging(), { vapidKey: '' }) //ERROR OCCURS HERE
      .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
          // Perform any other neccessary action with the token
        } else {
          // Show permission request UI
          console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      });
  };

}
```

Here is my app component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Message} from "./models/message";
import {AngularFireMessaging} from "@angular/fire/compat/messaging";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {MessagingService} from "./messaging.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'untitled3';

  messages: Array<Message> = [];

  constructor(private msg: AngularFireMessaging, private http: HttpClient, private service: MessagingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.requestPermission();
    let x = this.service.requestForToken();
    console.log(x);

  }
}
```

Please see the stacktrace below for the detailed error:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
at initializeApp (index.esm2017.js:423:29)
at getApp (index.esm2017.js:476:16)
at getMessagingInWindow (index.esm2017.js:1159:43)
at MessagingService.requestForToken (messaging.service.ts:47:33)
at AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:23:26)
at callHook (core.mjs:2450:22)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2419:17)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2370:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10357:21)
at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:11545:9)
```

I am using Angular Please assist. I have tried the following approaches

I tried adding the auth information

I Tried registering the service worker on both the index and the messaging service class

I tried calling the service worker module on the app module and calling the register there

Still no luck

Comment: Use `firebase/messaging` OR `firebase/compat` OR import from the CDN - don't mix and match them. In some files you call `getMessaging()`, in some you use `firebase.messaging()` and in some you call `importScripts` and then initialise the messaging component.

Comment: Hey @samthecodingman thank you so much for the reply man. I decided to use the firebase/messaging and I removed the firebase/compat and the CDN imports. I am still getting the same error though

Comment: Can you edit your question with the updated code and highlight which line is throwing the error? (e.g. `// <- error thrown here`)

Comment: Done, I have also added the stacktrace for the error

Comment: Based on the stack trace, `getApp()` (inside `getMessaging()`) doesn't think you've called `initializeApp()` in the same scope as where it is running. The messaging API has both `firebase/messaging` and `firebase/messaging/sw`, so maybe there's some distinction between the two that might be causing problems here. Unfortunately I haven't dealt with messaging from service workers enough to be of further help

Comment: I am stuck on something similar. I assume I have to use getApp() from import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app'; and potentially use it like provideStorage(() => {
            const app = getApp();
            const storage = getStorage(app);
            if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
                connectStorageEmulator(storage, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
            }
            return storage;
        }), or instantiate in the actual component but that seems wasteful